# Dev Script Doesn't Work In Remix With Cloud Flare Pages

Tags: remix, cloudflare-pages

I made a app with create-remix and I chose to use Cloud Flare Pages. Made the app but when I run `npm run dev` I get a error. I am on the latest node version (v17.3.1). I get this error the first time I run the dev script:

```
Watching Remix app in development mode...
Compiling worker to "/tmp/functionsWorker.js"...
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "../build"

    functions/[[path]].js:4:23:
      4 │ import * as build from "../build";
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~

1 error(s) and 0 warning(s) when compiling Worker.
Build failed with 1 error:
functions/[[path]].js:4:23: ERROR: Could not resolve "../build"
ERROR: "dev:wrangler" exited with 1.
```

Then if I run it again I get this error (probably because it builds the build folder the first time I run it before I get the error):

```
Watching Remix app in development mode...
Compiling worker to "/tmp/functionsWorker.js"...
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "../build"

    functions/[[path]].js:4:23:
      4 │ import * as build from "../build";
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~

1 error(s) and 0 warning(s) when compiling Worker.
Build failed with 1 error:
functions/[[path]].js:4:23: ERROR: Could not resolve "../build"
ERROR: "dev:wrangler" exited with 1.
```

Idk why I get this error as it is the default template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out on the remix discord server that you need to downgrade versions to fix this. To do that just run `npm install wrangler@beta`